# size of an ArrayBuffer

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Let suppose that i create ArrayBuffer with initial size equal 10

```scala
val buf = new ArrayBuffer[Int](10)
```

If i did call to method buf.size - got the size of buffer equal 0?

Comment: Surely this is something you could test reasonably easy, yes?

Comment: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/i5TYBYzSSZecONLbdZJUgQ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, because `size` (in this case inherited from `IndexedSeq`) refers to the number of elements in a collection, not the size or length of the underlying data structure.

Answer (score 11):

The array buffer class is meant to be an extensible array in which you can efficiently add elements at the end using `+=`. Initially, when created, the number of elements is 0 - that is referred to as the `size` of the collection.

Internally, the array buffer maintains an array of elements, which contains only `null`s when the buffer is created. Once an element is added, a write occurs into the array. When the array gets full, a new array with a double length is allocated and elements are copied into it. The [amortized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) time of adding an element remains O(1).

The ctor argument simply says what the initial length of the internal array will be. Although changing the initial length does not change the amortized cost of `+=` it can avoid unnecessary reallocations if you know how many elements you will add to it, thus being more efficient (in essence, decreasing the constant in the amortized analysis).

This argument is referred to as not the size, but as the capacity of the array buffer.

Comment: Many thanks for is enough full answer. It's all can see in the source code of scala collection, of course.

Comment: I asked because i consider an underlying ArrayBuffer how the data structure for implementation of bit set with adding an element O(1).

Comment: + provides is constant time access to elements

Comment: In that case, you can use the mutable bitset class.

Answer (score 3):

To initialize an arraybuffer with given size and value:

```
ArrayBuffer.fill(10)(5)
```

which will get:

```
scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)
```

Comment: Just to add on: If you need an array of Long use `ArrayBuffer.fill[Long](10)(5)`

Answer (score 2):

Using http://www.simplyscala.com/:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
val buf = new ArrayBuffer[Int](10)
buf: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer()

buf.size
res0: Int = 0

buf.length
res1: Int = 0
```

So I guess, the answer is not 10.